# error 500 on jquery datatables search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i created a table with jquery datatables. when I want to filter my table with search bar, the browser gives me an alert `DataTables warning: table id=grid - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`.

this is my code :

```
$("#grid").dataTable({
        "processing": true, // control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, // recommended to use serverSide when data is more than 10000 rows for performance reasons
        "info": true,   // control table information display field
        "stateSave": true,  //restore table state on page reload,
        "searching": true,
        "language": {
            "url": "/translate/datatables.fa-IR.json"
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],    // use the first inner array as the page length values and the second inner array as the displayed options
        "ajax": {
            "url": serviceBase + "/Auth/Admin/SearchOrders2/",
            "type": "GET",
            'beforeSend': function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorageService.get("authorizationData").token);
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "customerContact", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "isDone", "orderable": true },
            {
                "mRender":
                    function (data, type, row) {
                        var xxx = $scope.name1 = $filter("jalaliDateFromNow")(row["createdDate"]);
                        return "<span>" + $filter("jalaliDateFromNow")(row["orderCreationTime"]); +'</span>';
                    }, "orderable": true
            },
            { "data": "totalPrice", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "count", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "description", "orderable": true },
            {
                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-circle green tooltips" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>جزئیات</span></button>'
                },
                "orderable": false
            }
        ],
        "order": [[0, "desc"]]
    });
```

which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Error 500 means something happened wrong in back-end

Comment: I agree with @Aria there is something wrong with the backend, you should debug your backend for check your logs to see what the problem is. After you have a look you are still not sure share your backend code and I'll try to help.